# How can I scale my Cordova/PhoneGap app? Should I use "cordova-anyscreen", or is it too hacky?

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova, responsive-design

I'm having problems scaling my app on different devices that have the same proportions but with different -device-pixel-ratio factors.

Example: I have two 360x640 screens, and I make everything fit on one of them, but in the other the content is too big. It doesn't matter if I use em/rem units and change the font-size on html, or if I use media queries or px units. As long as the proportion is the same, they result is gonna be different.

My options are:

1. Use viewport units and drop support for older devices (or use Crosswalk and add 20mb to my 500kb app), or
2. Use [cordova-anyscreen](https://github.com/biodiv/cordova-anyscreen), which is the only thing I have found, but just seems wrong.

I might be missing something, but I have already spend two full days browsing Google and Stackoverflow, and I don't get how people do to make apps scale proportionally and density-independent. I really need help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do traditional way of work.

I use css to make it to suitable for other devices.

Just make sure to have,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

and use % or em if possible for your css.

To define different screen sizes in css, use

```
@media (min-width:400px) and (max-width:434px){}
/* This is for iPhone 6+ */
```

Comment: But that's the issue, the resolution (the actual CSS resolution) is the same, but the "window.devicePixelRatio" is different, so I can't use media queries. Anyway, I ended up using viewport units, which are a pain in the ass for many other reasons, but at least are more reliable in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help you, but its help me.

I have the same problem to compile my code to android/ios devices becouse of scaling. The lower menu not show.

But i found **Intel XDK** where you can build app for many devices and OS
Its use crosswalk/cordova etc. where there is automatic scale. Maybe this will help.

Try it out :)

Comment: Isn't Intel XDK a distribution of Cordova? I've never used it, but I guess it should output the same code, right? Where does the automatic scaling come in? Thanks!

Comment: @UnaiYécora just try it :) Just open folder code there, add required data in form there. And everythings else intel will do. There will be add a few new file. If you want to see what file etc : https://github.com/futer/pandachiifull/tree/master/main